# How to post JSON body and get response using Java httpclient 4.0.1?

Tags: json, post, httpclient

I am trying to get data by hitting lift igniter API, I have to pass json string to liftigniter API and  get response which will be also in json. The project is already built with http client 4.0.1.

Can any one suggest how can I achieve this, One more thing, I would like to mention I have to do it through same http client 4.0.1. I am not sure how can I send JSON formatted request?

I am using below code

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="javax.servlet.http.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.http.HttpEntity"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.http.HttpResponse"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpStatus"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpException"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethod"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.commons.httpclient.NameValuePair"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.*"%>



<%
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpMethod method = new PostMethod("https://query.petametrics.com/v2/model");

String json =  "{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"John\"}";
StringRequestEntity requestEntity = new StringRequestEntity(json, "application/json", "UTF-8");

//method.setRequestBody(requestEntity);
//method.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

//method.setQueryString(new NameValuePair[]{
  //      new NameValuePair("apiKey", "abc")
//});
//String json = "{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"John\"}";
//String json = "parmendra";
//out.println(json);
// StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json);
// method.setEntity(json);
 client.executeMethod(method);
 String shortUrlResponse = method.getResponseBodyAsString();
 out.println(shortUrlResponse);
%>
```